# How to prevent client side highscores from being faked

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When building a game you might add high scores, where the user has to play the game (using javascript) and when done the score gets submitted from the client to the server using for instance AJAX.

How do I stop the user from just changing the post data to whatever score they like and submitting that? Since they've got full control over al client-side actions.

Comment: You can't. Period. All the security and checks must be done server-side. Don't trust anything that comes from the front-end.

Comment: you should do the logic so that score is being counted in backend, store it in session or redis, then on game end just send get request as an action to process score and store and load the score from storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put you can't.

You can make it harder by using checksums and fancy hashing but in the end, it's all client sided, the client can be manipulated. You can make it harder for the casual user but not for the ones who know what their doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you really want to. Like @Vulpex mentioned, you use hashing but you can also place enough logic checks to invalidate a faked score.

For example, miles ran, hearts collected and coins collected can all be explained using an approximate formula. If you really want to enforce it, this could be one way to do it. Additionally, you could analyse a user's frequency of submitting and see whether user has jumped from score 10 to 9999 etc. In the end, it's not worth the effort.